# Compiling GCC 4.8.4 Error (CXX_ABI 1.3.8)

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile GCC version 4.8.4 using the following configuration parameters:

`--prefix=<path to gcc src> --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-linux-gnu`

However, when I try to `make` I get the following error:

```
make[5]: Entering directory '/DIR/gcc/objdir/x86_64-linux
gnu/libstdc++-v3/po'
msgfmt -o de.mo ../../../../libstdc++-v3/po/de.po
msgfmt -o fr.mo ../../../../libstdc++-v3/po/fr.po
msgfmt: /DIR/gcc/objdir/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8 not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
Makefile:460: recipe for target fr.mo failed
make[5]: *** [fr.mo] Error 1
make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
msgfmt: /DIR/gcc/objdir/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8 not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55)
```

**Try 1:** I've tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/lib32/`. Yet it does not seem to work.

**Try 2:** I've tried changing the GCC version used to compile it. I've used versions 4.7, 4.5, and 5. This also does not seem to work.

It seems that when compiling GCC, the wrong `libstdc++.so.6` is pull?
Any ideas or aclarations are welcome.

---

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux kernel 4.4.0-62

Comment: Getting gcc-4.8 : `sudo apt install g++-4.8` ... And you get version 4.8.5 : `/usr/bin/{ gcc-4.8, g++-4.8 }` .

Comment: @KnudLarsen I need to compile GCC version 4.8.4, downloading it won't work for my purposes

Comment: `--prefix=<path to gcc src>` looks very wrong.

Comment: @melpomene because?

Answer (score 1):

Building gcc-4.8.4 : Unpack mpfr-3.1.3.tar.xz, gmp-6.1.0.tar.xz, mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz into gcc-4.8.4/. Rename to have `gcc-4.8.4/{mpfr/, gmp/, mpc/}`.

`gcc` requires a build directory outside gcc-4.8.4/ : `mkdir build-gcc`

! If you configured inside gcc-4.8.4/, you will have to delete gcc-4.8.4/, and start from scratch.

```
cd build-gcc/

../gcc-4.8.4/configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc484 --program-suffix=484 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-mpfr-include=$(pwd)/../gcc-4.8.4/mpfr/src --with-mpfr-lib=$(pwd)/mpfr/src/.libs

make
```

---

---

`gcc-4.8.4` can be built with Ubuntu 14.04, not 16.04 . Result: `gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb` (24.4MB) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeWI3N1E2MXdrVm8/view?usp=sharing

Ubuntu 16.04 : gcc48, g++48 were tested with some applications, one has 400 c++ files : OK.

No dependencies, install with `sudo dpkg -i gcc48-c++_4.8.4-2ubuntu14_amd64.deb` Provides `/usr/local/bin/{ gcc48, g++48 }`

Comment: Even If I do what you suggest I still get the same error.

Comment: ? Which Ubuntu 16.04 ? 32bits or 64bits ? `uname -m` will reply i686 or x86_64

Comment: it's the 64bits version

Comment: No luck with Ubuntu 16.04 ... but an OK result, Ubuntu 14.04. I will update my above answer, when "gcc48, g++48" have been thoroughly tested on Ubuntu 16.04.